# How to include Bootstrap in One page?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have to create one page like offers (It will show all offers here).

I have to include bootstrap in this offers page only.

Thanks
SomuN

Answer (score 0):

You will have specific layout handle for this offers page 
e.g offers_index_index.xml

You need to add bootstrap in the head section of this file as follows:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <css src="Vendor_Module::css/bootstratp.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <script src="Vendor_Module::js/bootstrap.js"/>
</head>
```

Where as you can place js and css files in
Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js and Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css

Answer (score 0):

for adding JS use requirejs-config.js file

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        bootstrap: 'Vendor_Module::js/bootstrap.js'
    }
}
```

};

then use on particular page

```
define([
  "jquery",
  "bootstrap"
], 
function($, bootstrap) {
  "use strict";
// write here anything that u want
    return;
});
```

Now for Css

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
       <css src="Vendor_Module::css/bootstratp.css"/>
   </head>
</page>
```